# Read values from config text using glib

Tags: c, configuration, glib

I have the following Config.cfg

```
[Power]
Power8=8
Temp=5=1001
Hum=7=1002
Link=8=1003
Vol=9=1004

[Power]
Power10=10
Temp=5=1012
Hum=7=1013
Link=8=1014
Vol=9=1015
```

and with the usage of glib I want to read the values of each Power. I want something like 'if Power8=8 then return temp, hum, Link, Vol'else the same for Power10=10

I wrote this function

```
int read_config()
{

 GKeyFile *keyfile;
 GKeyFileFlags flags;
 GError *error = NULL;
 gsize length;
 gchar *temperatura, *humedad, *link, *voltage;


 // Create a new GKeyFile object and a bitwise list of flags.
 keyfile = g_key_file_new ();
 flags = G_KEY_FILE_KEEP_COMMENTS | G_KEY_FILE_KEEP_TRANSLATIONS;

 // Load the GKeyFile from keyfile.conf or return.
 if (!g_key_file_load_from_file (keyfile, "/home/pi/Desktop/Config.cfg", flags, &error))
 {
   g_error (error->message);
   return -1;
 }
  printf("[Power]\n");
 if(g_key_file_get_integer(keyfile,"Power","Power8",NULL) == 8)
 {
   temperatura=g_key_file_get_string(keyfile,"Power","Temp",NULL);
   humedad=g_key_file_get_string(keyfile,"Power","Hum",NULL);
   link=g_key_file_get_string(keyfile,"Power","Link",NULL);
   voltage=g_key_file_get_string(keyfile,"Power","Volt",NULL);
   printf("Power8:%d\n",g_key_file_get_integer(keyfile,"Power","Power8",NULL));
   printf("Temp:%s\n",temperatura);
   printf("Hum:%s\n",humedad);
   printf("Link:%s\n",link);
   printf("Vol:%s\n",voltage);
 }
else
 {
   temperatura=g_key_file_get_string(keyfile,"Power","Temp",NULL);
   humedad=g_key_file_get_string(keyfile,"Power","Hum",NULL);
   link=g_key_file_get_string(keyfile,"Power","Link",NULL);
   voltage=g_key_file_get_string(keyfile,"Power","Volt",NULL);
   printf("Power10:%d\n",g_key_file_get_integer(keyfile,"Power","Power10",NULL));
   printf("Temp:%s\n",temperatura);
   printf("Hum:%s\n",humedad);
   printf("Link:%s\n",link);
   printf("Vol:%s\n",voltage);
 }
```

}

But it returns me the values of Power10 and also Vol=(Null)

```
[Power]
Power8=8
Temp=5=1012
Hum=7=1013
Link=8=1014
Vol=(Null)
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html#glib-Key-value-file-parser.description) clearly states:

> Note that in contrast to the Desktop Entry Specification, groups in key files may contain the same key multiple times; the last entry wins. Key files may also contain multiple groups with the same name; they are merged together.

Thus, your file is not a valid glib keyfile since it tries to define the same key multiple times, expecting each group to be an "object". That's not how it works, unfortunately.

The `Vol` issue seems to simply be the wrong key, you're calling with `"Volt"` but the file has `Vol`.

Comment: You are right! Now I see the documentation. But for my education what is the problem with Vol=(null)?

Comment: I found it. I had different name declaration